# $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ and its ideals $(2)$ and $(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Consider $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$, that is obviously not the ring of integers of $\mathbf{Q}[\sqrt{-3}]$, and its ideal $P=(2,1+\sqrt{-3})$. I know that $P^2=(2)P$ and that $P\neq (2)$. I think that $P$ is  a prime ideal since its norm $N(P)=N(2)=2^2$ is a power of a prime. I want to prove that $P$ is the unique prime ideal containing $(2)$ and so $(2)$ is not product of prime ideal in $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$. I think that if $(2)=PQ$, with $Q$ prime ideal, then $N(2)=N(P)N(Q)$ and so $N(Q)=1$, then $Q$ is trivial. But I can't see why $P$ is the unique prime ideal containing $(2)$. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you compute $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(2)$? This should give you the information you need.

Comment: $\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(2)\simeq \mathbf{Z}[X]/(2,X^2-3)$...but I can't see the solution. Can you explain your idea? Morevover, do you think what I have written before is correct? Thanks

Comment: I think the point Claudius is making is that the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ containing $(2)$ are in bijection with the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(2)$. As you note, we have $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(2) \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle 2, X^{2}-3 \rangle \cong (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[X]/\langle (X+1)^{2} \rangle$. It is straighforward to see that there are exactly $3$ ideals of the latter, namely $\langle 0 \rangle, \langle X+1 \rangle$, and $\langle 1 \rangle$. These correspond with $(2), P,$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]$ respectively.

Comment: This is a good start. Now show that $\mathbb Z[X]/(2,X^2-3)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^2-1)$ and notice that $X^2-1 = (X-1)^2$ in characteristic $2$.

Comment: I am not sure how you define the norm in this context, so I cannot comment on that.

Comment: Probably for the last statement the norm is not necessary: if $(2)$ were produt of two distinct prime ideals, say $PQ=(2)$, then $(2)\subset P$ and $(2)\subset Q$, a contradiction since it is contained just in $P$. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be as follows: Consider the surjective ring homomorphism
$$\phi: \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}] \rightarrow \mathbb{F}_2$$ defined by
$$\phi(a+b\sqrt{-3}) = (a+b) \mod 2$$Then the kernel of $\phi$ is your ideal $P$ and thus, according to one of the ring isomorphism theorems,
$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/P \cong \mathbb{F}_2$$
which is a field, so $P$ is maximal and hence also prime.